# query to find specific word in a cloumn using oracle database

Tags: sql, database, string, oracle

can anyone help me in the below query.

I wanted to find the records which have "word1" in col1 and we can write the below query for that but do we have any other option/operator that we can find the exact word in the col1 without prefix and postfix.

```
Select col1, col2 from table1
where col1 like '%word1%' 
or col1 like '%word1' 
or col1 like 'word1%'
or col1 = 'word1';
```

Note: I know that we can use contains operator but it uses the index which i don't want.

Please let me know is there any other way to represent above quer in a simple manner.

Comment: You only need `col1 like '%word1%'`. The rest is unnecessary. Also, why wouldn't you want to use the index? The index would make the query faster.

Comment: Building a TEXT index so you can use the `contains()` operator is your only alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want something like `like` .. but why?
If it is for a learning, you can use `INSTR()`

```
Select col1, col2 from table1
where INSTR(col1,'word1') > 0
```

Otherwise best approach is

```
Select col1, col2 from table1
    where col1 like '%word%'
```